# Node installed, but not NPM

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, homebrew

I installed node with brew 'brew install node', and I get a warning message

```
'Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully'.
```

When I put in node -v, I can indeed see the current version of node, however when I try to find the current version of npm, I get this error.

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

Is the reason that NPM does not exist because the post-install step did not complete successfully ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup, that thing happened to me too. After a lot of searching I came to a solution. I think this would help you.

```
sudo brew uninstall node
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew install node
sudo chown -R myusername /usr/local
brew link --overwrite node
sudo brew postinstall node
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Phwew, ran the commands and it worked. I really have to get more knowledge about working in the shell.Thanks Sk Arif !

Comment: Did not need sudo on last step